# Is matrix $Svv^\top S$ positive semidefinite, given $S$ is symmetric positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Is matrix $Svv^\top S$ positive semidefinite, given $S$ is symmetric positive semidefinite? Where $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$,  $S\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your definition of positive semidefinite includes that $S$ is symmetric. Then
$$
Svv^\top S=Svv^\top S^\top=(Sv)(Sv)^\top.
$$
$$
A\triangleq (Sv)^\top\quad\Rightarrow\quad (Sv)(Sv)^\top=A^\top A
$$
Any matrix of the form $A^TA$ is positive-semidefinite: because if $A$ is $m\times n$, then for any $x$ of size $n\times 1$,
$$
x^T(A^TA)x=(Ax)^TAx=y^Ty=\sum_{j=1}^my_j^2\geq0,
$$
where $y=Ax$.

Comment: Yes, S is symmetric. Why $(Sv)(Sv)^\top$ would be positive semidefinite?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: That is true $\forall\; A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, but $Sv\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, plus $(Sv)^\top(Sv)\in \mathbb{R}$, whereas $(Sv)(Sv)^\top\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

Comment: Yes, if you correct your second $(Sv)^TSv$ to $Sv(Sv)^T$. But I don't see your point. Why "but"?

Comment: $(Sv)(Sv)^\top\neq (Sv)^\top(Sv)$,

Comment: Of course. The first one is an $n\times n$ matrix and the second one a $1\times 1$. I still don't see your point. Why "but"?

Comment: Ok, now makes sense. Thanks a lot, appreciate!

Comment: Glad I could help!